# Import Excel to numpy to solve linear equations

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have 2 matrices in 2 Excel files. A is 57x56 (first row is the labels) and b is 57x1. I'm trying to find the solution to Ax=b using python.

What I did:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
A=pd.read_excel("56x56.xlsx")
b=pd.read_excel("56x1.xlsx")
A=np.matrix(A)
b=np.matrix(b)
x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
```

this gives me an error "float() argument must be a string or a number". I wonder if this is because the first label-row in A. If so what could be a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Have A und b printed to know what the data looks like. In case it is a nested list you can skip the first row with A[1:]

Comment: what does `type(A)` say ? You could try `A = A.values`

Comment: What does A.head() say ?

Comment: @moritz type(A) is an ndarray

Answer (score 1):

Without further knowledge we can just guess. Probably the first row is treated as header. Try:

```
A=pd.read_excel("56x56.xlsx",sheet='Sheet1',header = None)
```

Furthermore the data should be already an array. Therfore `A = A.values` should do unless you would like to explicitly convert it e.g by `A = np.array(A.values,dtype=float)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your intermediate data structures:

`A=np.matrix(A)
b=np.matrix(b)`

are not doing what you want/expect, and changing to:

`A=A.as_matrix()
b=b.as_matrix()`

resolves this.